# how to share text on facebook from thi iphone using Titanium?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium, appcelerator

I have implement one iPhone application using Titanium. Now I want to share application link or text on facebook I don't know which api I have to use and how to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any code yet you can share? [Ti.Facebook](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook-module) changed in version 1.6 and uses the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) since then. There's a decent amount of [documentation](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/facebook_query.js) in the KS as well.

You want to start by logging in to Facebook with the Graph API using the `Ti.Facebook.createLoginButton` and then `Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath` for anything you would need. To share a [dialog](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Facebook.dialog-method.html) is probably best.